# Which mysterious process sent data out of my computer?

Tags: process, netstat

Using `vnstat`, I observed a lot of uploaded data from my computer and I don't know which process sent data out of my computer.

I installed `nethogs` to monitor live data transfer but  seems `nethogs` doesn't see the process which is sending data, the system monitor shows more data than nethogs. (see picture)

[image]

How can I find out which process is sending all that data?

Update: 
After a long time of investigation, it poped in my mind that few months ago, I added in my crontab, a ping each 5 minutes to one of my website on Heroku to prevent the dyno to fall asleep. I remove this task and no more mysterious data sending. It is weird that `nethog` was not able to spot that.
Thank you for the help!

PS: It didn't work to ping the dyno on Heroku to prevent it to fall asleep.

Comment: Try running nethogs with sudo. Some programs/ports are hidden from non root users